# Using the concurrently package, spawn a process for each file in a directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

Using the [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) package, I'd like to spawn a separate process for each file in a specific directory. Currently, that looks something like this:

**package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
      "mass": "concurrently \"npm:accounts/*\"",
      "accounts/1": "ts-node src/index.ts --settings %npm_lifecycle_event%.json",
      "accounts/2": "ts-node src/index.ts --settings %npm_lifecycle_event%.json",
      "accounts/3": "ts-node src/index.ts --settings %npm_lifecycle_event%.json"     
    }
}
```

This is using `%npm_lifecycle_event%` to insert the name of the script as the name of the json file and works well, but there are some shortcomings I'd like to address:

1. `ts-node src/index.ts --settings %npm_lifecycle_event%.json` will never change, but this flow requires that it's duplicated for every additional account
2. There is no automatic scanning of a directory to product these scripts; they need to be added into `package.json` individually.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
{
    "scripts": {
      "mass": "concurrently \"dir:accounts/* ts-node src/index.ts --settings %filename%"",   
    }
}
```

In the example above, the intention would be to retrieve all of the files within the `accounts` directory, then pass the name of the file to the following command, for each file in the set.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by orchestrating this in a separate script:

```
import concurrently from "concurrently";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

const accountsDirectory = path.resolve("accounts");
console.log(accountsDirectory);

const accountFiles = fs.readdirSync(accountsDirectory)
    .filter((fileName) => /.*\.json/gi.test(fileName))
    .map((fileName) => path.join(accountsDirectory, fileName))
    .sort();

const { result } = concurrently(
    accountFiles.map((accountFile) => ({
        name: path.basename(accountFile),
        command: `ts-node src/index.ts --settings ${accountFile}`
    }))
);

result.then(
    (success) => {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(success);
    }, 
    (failure) => {
        console.log("failure");
        console.log(failure);
    }
);
```